# Retrieve the members of a class

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to retrieve members of a DBpedia ontology class using the public SPARQL endpoint but the following queries return empty :

```sql
select ?entity
where
{
?entity rdf:type dbo:city .
}
LIMIT 10

select ?entity
where
{
?entity a dbo:city .
}
LIMIT 10
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: By naming convention on DBpedia, class names start with uppercase char and have Pascal Style, i.e. `dbo:City`. Or `dbo:SoccerClub`, or ...

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your two queries are effectively the same query. 'a' is just a built in abbreviation for rdf:type